# AngularJS HTTP GET request returning cached data

Tags: angularjs, http-get

In my AngularJS app I am sending HTTP GET request as below.

```
MyService.HttpReq("testUrl", "GET", null);
```

`HttpReq` Method is defined in a service and implemented as below:

```
this.HttpReq = function(URL, method, payload)
{
    $http({
        url: URL,
        method: method,
        cache: false,
        data: postData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).success(function(response)
    {
        console.log("Success: "+JSON.stringify(response));

    }).error(function(data, status)
    {
       console.error("Error");

    });
}
```

First of all is this the right way of sending HTTP request in AngularJS?
The problem that I am facing is, some times I get cached data as response and HTTP request is not hitting the server. what can be the issue?

**UPDATE**

As per the comment and answer I have updated my HTTP request code as below, but still getting same issue.

```
this.HttpReq = function(URL, method, payload)
{
    $http({
        url: URL, 
        method: method, 
        cache: false,
        data: payload,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'
        }
    }).
    then(
        function(response) 
        {
            var data = response.data;
            console.log("Success: "+JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
        function(response) 
        {
            var data = response.data || "Request failed";
            var status = response.status;
            console.error("Error: "+JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What method do you use in your HttpReq method? GET or POST..or both?

Comment: I use Both GET and POST

Comment: .success and .error are deprecated, use 2 callback functions instead.

Comment: Can you show how to use it?

Comment: @A_user: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http :) But I don't know why you get cached data.

Comment: @gyc I have updated the call as per the link but still getting cached data. Is the issue in doing calls in sequence? I am calling one HttpGet in success call back of other HttpGet, is this OK to do so?

Comment: Can you make a plunker that reproduces the issue? It will be useful to see how you're chaining the requests.

Comment: @gyc I will create plunker with the sequence of GET and I will post it here. But in general is it ok to call HttpGet in success call back of another HttpGet? I don't see any issue in it.

Comment: Technically it is feasible. Using the keyworkds "angular promise chaining" should get you some results. In general we try to make as few API calls as possible. In a "real" app you would be required to change your API so that it returns all the data you need in 1 request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **cache: false** attribute to config object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching

Also you can add header: 'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'

Comment: Please check my updated question, I have just now tried with `cache: false` but I still see cached data.

Comment: $http doesn't cache data by default.

Comment: Calls that I am doing are in sequence, in success call back of one I am sending another request, is that the right way?

Comment: Also you can add header: 'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'

Comment: @A_user The example at the bottom of the doc for $http is the right way to have a generic function

Comment: I have updated my question, I am using the $http call same way.

Answer (score 2):

IE Browsers will catch ajax get requests even if we add cache control headers to the response. Only way i found to solve the issue is to add some random parameter to the request. Please make sure the api have no problem even if you send extra parameters

```
 MyService.HttpReq("testUrl?ts=" + Date.now(), "GET", null);
```

Comment: OH! I am using chrome for testing but still I am facing this issue.

Comment: There is no use of adding cache-control header to the request. It should be set to response header in server side. Please try adding a random parameter like timestamp as i shown in example. It should work.